# sharepoint online remote event receiver does not working

Tags: office365, sharepoint-2013, event-receiver

Hello i recently started to developing sharepoint 2013 .
I deply my solution to office365 online account and to my solution i attached remote event receiver.
This event receiver should listen to particular events(in this case adding to a custom list)
and then perform action.
Problem is that this action is never performed. It seems that event receiver is not event firing when event occurs.
Any ideas ? anyone had similar problem?
best regards

Answer (score 2):

There is a distinct difference if you are adding a remote event receiver to an instance of a list (for example) that you have deployed together with your App into "application web" or it is an event receiver for exiting list on the "host web".

The former case: VS2012 will do everything for you and you'd just need to write your logic in the event methods created.

The latter case: is a bit more complicated, you'd need to write some logic and register your remote event during application installation. A good article about that:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knewton/archive/2012/12/11/defining-content-in-host-web-from-an-app-for-sharepoint.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that you also need to make sure that your remote event listener is in your package. 
Check out Package.package under your sharepoint project and make sure it's added.If not click edit & add it to the package.
I spent a lot of time figuring out a similar problem and this turned out to be the solution for me!

Another thing to watch for is when adding a list and an event listener for that list: The event listener has to have the same type as the list or point to that specific list.